# Notify-send doesn't work from crontab

Tags: cron, notify-send

I made a script that should notify me when there's a new chapter of manga that I'm reading.
I used the command notify-send to do this.
The program works when I am trying to run it in terminal.
The notification is showing.
However, when I placed this in my crontab, the notification doesn't show.
I'm pretty sure that the program is running since I made it to create a file for me.
The file was created, but the notification didn't show.

Here's my script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash   
#One Piece Manga reminder    
#I created a file named .newop that contains the latest chapter.    
let new=$(cat ~/.newop)    
wget --read-timeout=30 -t20 -O .opreminder.txt http://www.mangareader.net/103/one-piece.html

if (( $(cat .opreminder.txt | grep "One Piece $new" | wc -l) >=1 ))    
then    
    (( new+=1 ))    
    echo $new    
    echo $new > ~/.newop    
    notify-send "A new chapter of One Piece was released."    
else    
    notify-send "No new chapter for One Piece."    
    notify-send "The latest chapter is still $new."    
fi        
exit
```

And here's what I wrote in my crontab

```
0,15,30,45 12-23 * * 3   /home/jchester/bin/opreminder.sh
```

Comment: Just a reminder, all commands in crontab need to have their path in front of them as they run as root. Attaching script and line in crontab would help otherwise we are just guessing at your problem

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I just did.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Notifications are a "GUI" thing, cron is a "console" thing. There is no gaurentee that lib-notify will be able to find a way to display the message.  Instead you should consider sending data to stdout and let cron's messaging take care of sending the info. Normally an email is sent.

Comment: In some cases setting the DISPLAY variable up may help as well, e.g.: `export DISPLAY=:0`.

Comment: For `16.04`, this one worked for me


`*/1 * * * * eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";/usr/bin/notify-send -i  appointment  -c "im" "Keep Working"`

Comment: @MidhunKM Does not work with 20.04.5.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Commands need to reference their location. So `notify-send` needs to be `/usr/bin/notify-send`

All commands need to have their full path.

Use the `whereis notify-send` command to see where your commands "live"

Comment: Does that include cat, wget, if, let, grep, echo, etc?

Comment: If the whereis command returns a value yes, "if/echo/exit" is the exception as its internal to bash, you will note "whereis id" returns "if:" denoting internal command

Comment: `enable -a` will show you the internal commands.

Comment: At least on my system, `notify-send` is on the `PATH` even for a cron job. See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/346580/30266) below.

Comment: It isn't the solution for Ubuntu 17.04. See https://askubuntu.com/a/472769/413683 and https://askubuntu.com/a/834479/413683 instead.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that cron scripts do not run under the user session, and have no concept of the environment of the user's login session. As notify-send requires connecting to a dbus session bus to send the notification, it will not matter what path the binary is called from, when it doesn't connect to the correct session bus.

Comment: This is NOT the answer. Sure, if executable cannot be located,it won't run, BUT:
1. notify-send is on the PATH so it will be located
2. even if it wasn't on the PATH, and you specify full path it still will not work, because actually DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS has to be set for notify-send. And the correct answer is from kmir.

Comment: Did not work for me. Agree with Kris.

Answer (score 46):

Things seem to be different on 13.04, at least in Gnome Shell.

First, this is what `env` prints when run from user `zzyxy`'s (not root's) cron job:

```
HOME=/home/zzyxy
LOGNAME=zzyxy
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/zzyxy
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/zzyxy
```

To get `notify-send` to work, it seems to be necessary to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable, as per [DahitiF's comment](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1727148&p=10675502#post10675502) on ubuntuforums.org. Just prepend the following to your actual job description:

```
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
```

It doesn't seem to be necessary to set `DISPLAY`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what finally worked for me. On Xubuntu, you have to change `gnome-session` to `xfce4-session`.

Comment: This is the only answer to work for 14.04, along with the obvious hint of the accepted one.

Comment: I had no `gnome-session` and used `gnome-shell` instead (be careful there is also a `gnome-shell-calendar-server` so `pgrep` will get 2 pids). I also needed `DISPLAY=:0` because I'm using 2 phisical screens and it was not defined.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Openbox (like on CB++) swap in `openbox` for `gnome-session`.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer, and the accepted answer is not even correct, it talks about DISPLAY variable which is not even needed, nor it actually solves the problem.

Comment: Use `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` to findout your session name, mine was `plasma` because I used Kubuntu.

Comment: on I3 window manager, use `i3` for `gnome-session`

Answer (score 31):

Command `notify-send` would not show the message on your screen when started by cron.
Just add target display at the top of your script, for example:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: This is what I had to do in 14.10 too. Otherwise I would get this error `gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Option parsing failed: Cannot open display:`

Comment: This. And use `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal to make sure your display really is `:0` (it usually is, but not always).

Comment: Only this worked for me, I am using Linux Mint

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and this did not work DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is the issue there.

Answer (score 17):

I use i3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. My way to solve this is:

`* * * * *  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "this is dog!"`

Comment: That worked for me, Added `export` line on top of my script file.
`export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)`

Comment: That worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS as well.

Comment: Thank you. `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)` was exactly what i needed.

Comment: Thanks that works fine.

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu 14.04 at least, [klrmr's response above](https://askubuntu.com/a/346580/255814) is the correct answer.  It does not appear to be necessary to set DISPLAY or articulate full paths for notify-send or anything otherwise normally in $PATH.

Below is a cron script I'm using to shutdown a virtual machine when a laptop's battery state becomes too low.  The line setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in klrmr's response above is the modification that finally got the warnings working correctly.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# if virtual machine is running, monitor power consumption
if pgrep -x vmware-vmx; then
  bat_path="/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/"
  if [ -e "$bat_path" ]; then
    bat_status=$(cat $bat_path/status)
    if [ "$bat_status" == "Discharging" ]; then
      bat_current=$(cat $bat_path/capacity)
      # halt vm if critical; notify if low
      if [ "$bat_current" -lt 10 ]; then
        /path/to/vm/shutdown/script
        echo "$( date +%Y.%m.%d_%T )" >> "/home/user/Desktop/VM Halt Low Battery"
        elif [ "$bat_current" -lt 15 ]; then
            eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
            notify-send -i "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/24/battery-caution.svg"  "Virtual machine will halt when battery falls below 10% charge."
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked perfectly for me as well, I just added the "eval..." line to my script that I run from crontab - now it works perfectly

Comment: I also needed to add this to the top of my script: export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)

Answer (score 5):

In my case with ubuntu 16.04 any explicit path was required, I solve the problem just adding

> DISPLAY=:0

at firsts lines of the crontab, before call notify-send.

Comment: This is the only thing necessary to get it to work on 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

This took forever to make work on ubuntu 15.10, Had to add a source to get the users normal env vars. my display was :1 for some reason as well.
Using the gnome-session first results pid for DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS lookup.

```
# Crontab is
* 21 * * * /bin/sh /home/tristik/cron.sh
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh 
# cron.sh
# Notifies the user of date and time
source /home/tristik/.bashrc
pid=$(pgrep -u tristik gnome-session | head -n 1)
dbus=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$dbus
export HOME=/home/tristik
export DISPLAY=:1
/usr/bin/notify-send 'title' "$(/bin/date)"
```

Comment: used this to solve a screensaver problem

Answer (score 1):

First culprit is your crontab file, you also need to mention the user name with which the script has to be executed, better keep it as root

```
0,15,30,45 12-23 * * 3 root   /home/jchester/bin/opreminder.sh
```

and then you should use the user_name of the GUI user inside the script and prepend it to notify-send with "sudo or su" to execute the command as a user who owns the GUI

example :

```
su gnome_user_name -c 'notify-send "summary" "body"'
```

or

```
sudo -u gnome_user_name notify-send "summary" "body"
```

where `gnome_user_name` is the username of the user who started the GUI session
it is you who logged in, and if you want to make it a dynamic pick, you can get it from

```
GNOME_USER=`ps -eo uname,cmd | grep gnome-session| head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1 `
```

example :

```
su $GNOME_USER -c 'notify-send "summary" "body"'
```

or

```
sudo -u $GNOME_USER notify-send "summary" "body"
```

Comment: I think that when your username is longer than X characters, your usernma is truncated: For example, my username is `oniltonmaciel`, but `$GNOME_USER` would show `onilton+` (doesn't work)

Comment: fixed it with better command

Comment: Better edit the sudoers and avoid root shell.

Answer (score 1):

The way the binary retrieves the dbus address seems to have changed lately. On Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) with "notify-send 0.7.6", the following two variables are needed:

```
export HOME=/home/$notify_user
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

The statement by 'krlmlr' evaluates fine and sets the correct address, but the dialog won't pop up from a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

In the case below, I was calling notify-send from a python script that monitors memory of processes as I've been having issues with XOrg memory growth.

The example below should work and does not output the `warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input` warning.

**myscript_cron.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0 called: `date`
export USER=`whoami`
export HOME=/home/$USER
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u ${USER} gnome-session | head -n 1)/environ | tr '\0' '\n'| sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//')

cd <path_to_my_script>

/usr/bin/python3.7 ./<my_script>.py 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

**crontab:**

Note: Ran as `crontab -e` in my user account and not sudo

```
* * * * * <path_to_my_script>/myscript_cron.sh  >> <path_to_my_script>/cron.log 2>&1
```

I like to monitor output of cron calls to a log file so I can debug the shell script but I don't want it to be polluted with the stdout of the python script. I output the python script to a separate log.

Comment: I tried quite a few solutions. Only this one worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printenv` for print environment variables from your normal terminal. And then paste all environment variables in starting of crontab file.

Comment: Please don't submit images of text.  We can't work with it easily, can't copy it accurately, and some users can't read it at all. Instead copy-paste the text into the body of your question and render the text in `monospace` font so it is easier to work with.  You can use the editing tools above the text box when you edit your post or you can also use Markdown language.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got this to work with the cinnamon desktop on Ubuntu 15.10, using the following recipe:

```sh
if [ ! -v DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS ]; then
  pid=$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME cinnamon-sessio)
  eval "export $(\grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ)"
fi
notify-send "$RESUME" "$INFO"
```

The trick was to realize that 'cinnamon-session' is too long for pgrep to find:

```
$ pgrep -u $LOGNAME cinnamon-session
$ pgrep -u $LOGNAME cinnamon
30789
30917
30965
30981
31039
31335
$ ps -a | \grep cinnamon
30789 tty2     00:00:00 cinnamon-sessio
30917 tty2     00:00:02 cinnamon-settin
30965 tty2     00:00:00 cinnamon-launch
30981 tty2     00:04:15 cinnamon
31039 tty2     00:00:00 cinnamon-killer
31335 tty2     00:00:00 cinnamon-screen
$ ps a | \grep cinnamon
 4263 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep cinnamon
30779 tty2     Ssl+   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session --run-script cinnamon-session-cinnamon
30789 tty2     Sl+    0:00 cinnamon-session --session cinnamon
30917 tty2     Sl+    0:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/cinnamon-settings-daemon
30965 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/cinnamon-launcher
30970 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-printer
30981 tty2     Sl+    4:16 cinnamon --replace
31039 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/cinnamon-killer-daemon
31335 tty2     Sl+    0:00 cinnamon-screensaver
$ pgrep -u $LOGNAME cinnamon-sessio
30789
```

I also had to use \grep because my grep is aliased to

```
$ alias grep
alias grep='grep -n --color=always'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script in crontab is running as root, the answers above will probably not work. Try this function, which works fine for me in 16.04 :

```sh
notify_all() {
    local title=$1
    local msg=$2

    who | awk '{print $1, $NF}' | tr -d "()" |
    while read u d; do
        id=$(id -u $u)
        . /run/user/$id/dbus-session
        export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
        export DISPLAY=$d
        su $u -c "/usr/bin/notify-send '$title' '$msg'"
    done 
}
```

( Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344377/7286 )

Answer (score 0):

Better to rely on `dbus-session` process, it should be running for all systems where `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is present.

Create a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# notify.sh

environs=`pidof dbus-daemon | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{printf "/proc/%s/environ ", $1}'`
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=`cat $environs 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' '\n' | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS | cut -d '=' -f2-`
export DISPLAY=:0

notify-send "It works!"
```

Make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x ~/notify.sh
```

Add it to crontab:

```
* * * * * $HOME/notify.sh
```

Comment: FYI - Setting DISPLAY was not needed for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue caused by calling `python3` in crontab with `UTF-8` locale.**

**TL;DR:** prefix call in crontab w/ locale as in:

```
*/5 * * * * LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8 LANG=en_US.utf-8 ~/.local/bin/watson-notify
```

See also [click and python3](http://click.pocoo.org/python3/):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/watson/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
    cli.cli()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 759, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 693, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/_unicodefun.py", line 123, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/ for mitigation steps.

This system supports the C.UTF-8 locale which is recommended.
You might be able to resolve your issue by exporting the
following environment variables:

    export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
    export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

For all crontab script that use libnotify, I use this:

```bsh
notify_user() {
    local user=$(whoami)
    notify-send -u normal -t 4000 "System Backup" "Starting backup"
}

notify_user # and do other stuff
```

It works even if I use cron in root mode.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the X_user and X_userid. Replace both in the command bellow.

## Solution with systemd

/etc/systemd/system/opreminder.service #Service file

```
[Unit]
Descrption=some service to run

[Service]
User=[X_user]
ExecStart=/home/jchester/bin/opreminder.sh
```

/etc/systemd/system/opreminder.timer  #timer file

```
[Unit]
Description=Some desc


[Timer]
OnCalendar=0,15,30,45 12-23 * * 3 

[Install]
WantedBy=list.timer.target
```

/home/jchester/bin/opreminder.sh #The script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo -u [X_user] DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/[X_userid]/bus notify-send 'Hello world!' 'This is an example notification.'
```

No need to use sudo -u if the service file is already set with the intended user

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications#Usage_in_programming

Answer (score 0):

This makes it work on 19.10:

```
eval "export $(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session | head -n 1 | xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ | egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with setting `DISPLAY=:0.0` worked for me for years. In 20.04, it suddenly stopped working. It turned out that now the display coordinates changed, it's now `:1`. So

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Solved the problem.

The styling of the popup is ugly, but it's a different story.

### Update

What I wrote above was about the case of upgrading from 16.04 via 18.04 to 20.04.

But when I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch (still keeping `/home/$USER`), it stopped working (probably, `notify-send` is now implemented by a different program).

So, now the `DISPLAY` variable is not relevant, but here is what I need to define: `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus`.

So a line in crontab could look like this:

```
14 * * * *     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send 'Hello!'
```

The pop-up has the same styling as when running `notify-send` from a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is using the **fish shell**, like me, here is my script which essentially does the same as the bash script of @denis.peplin. I use it to send a warning when the battery charge is low.

```
#!/bin/fish

# set environment variables
pidof dbus-daemon | tr ' ' '\n' | while read -l pid
        set environs $environs /proc/$pid/environ
end
set -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS (cat $environs 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' '\n' | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS>
set -x DISPLAY :0

# perform actual job
set capacity (cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
if test $capacity -le $argv[1]
        /usr/local/bin/dunstify -u critical -t 10000 "Battery low!" "Plug in asap."
end
```

I had to avoid `awk`, because its return type is a string containing two paths that are separated by a space. A fish variable does not extract the two paths, but stores the whole string, causing conflicts when using `cat $environs`. Using a while loop that appends the paths to the variable achieves the intended.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with using `root` user with `notify-send`. I realized this when I saw that `sudo notify-send` didn't work on the terminal but just `notify-send` (i.e. with current user) did.
So instead of editing the usual `/etc/crontab` which is used by `root`, I had a custom cron script created for  `myusername`. Please check my whole answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710326/534253).