# How to use notify-send with crontab?

Tags: cron

I really read many tutorials, but crontab doesn't start notify send.

What I've tried:

1. `etc/crontab`

   added at the end:

   ```
   15 * * * * notify-send 'crontab' 'test'
   ```
2. with crontab interface:

   ```
   crontab -e
   ```

   added at the end:

   ```
   15 * * * * notify-send 'crontab' 'test'
   ```

Comment: Try to run .sh script by editing `eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";`

Comment: @Lnux , Where do I place this line? On .sh file before the `notify-send 'crontab' 'test'` ?

Comment: yes in your bash script before notify-send

Comment: on `16.04` this one worked

    `*/1 * * * * eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";/usr/bin/notify-send -i  appointment  -c "im" "Keep Working"`

Comment: `* * * * * export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ) && DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "Foo bar"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested by @Lnux:

Create a .sh, for example `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";

#Code:
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "Test"
```

Then set up crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

And at the bottom, add:

```
* * * * * /home/myUser/test.sh
```

*Obs.: you can place your .sh file in another location and don't forget to allow executing it.*

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I was able to replace the provided `eval ...` with: `eval "export | egrep 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS|DISPLAY'"`.

Comment: I got a large output which I don't understand, so I replaced the `eval ...` with the line suggested by @pdoherty926 and I got this output. `declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1002/bus"
declare -x DISPLAY=":1"` . So I changed the next line to `DISPLAY=:1 notify-send "Test"`. Still no notification with crontab

Answer (score 6):

Crontab is running in the background and without specified graphical output it will show nothing. So you should spicify, which output would you like to use. To achieve that, put `export DISPLAY=:0 &&` before you command, e.g.

`15 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && notify-send 'I am alive!'`

Comment: 'DISPLAY=:' or 'DISPLAY='

Comment: DISPLAY=:0 , the colon is neccessary.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code using ` crontab -e` using user and root and nothing happens...

Comment: well that is unexpected, because I did the same (except I changed 15 minutes to *) and it works. Try to change the DISPLAY variable to 1 or 2, I have seen it help sometimes, although I don't fully understand why.

Comment: Do you have to reboot to start?

Comment: No, it works with next launch-time

Comment: @Michael I think your solution didn't work because I use multiple desktop enfironment.

Comment: I also use several desktops, but it's possible, that the numbering depends on graphical card/driver. I have similar problem with another machine to which I was connected via ssh and was unable to start notify-send with DISPLAY=:0.

Comment: Try `echo $DISPLAY` in an xshell, to see to what it is set on your system. However, on Xubuntu-20.04 it didn't work, but `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000; notify-send -u critical TEST displaytest` worked, while I'm the only desktop user, and my UID is 1000, which is the default for all xyUbuntus  so far. You may as well evaluate the UID at runtime.