# crontab + notify-send + Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cron, notify-send

In my Ubuntu 16.04 , 64 bit OS, I tried the following

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && notify-send Hey "How are you"
```

And

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/notify-send Hey "How are you"
```

But, unfortunately, it is not working.

I found in other threads that the above command works.

How to run it on my machine?

The command `notify-send Hey "How are you"` works on the terminal.

Also the command `* * * * * echo "trying to notify at $(date)" >> /home/user/Desktop/test.txt` works fine from crontab file

The output of `$ echo $DISPLAY` is `:0`

also

```
$ who -u
cosmicraga   tty7         2016-11-07 06:45 06:12        2524 (:0)
cosmicraga   pts/1        2016-11-07 12:54   .          6333 (:0)
cosmicraga   pts/17       2016-11-07 12:50 00:02        6333 (:0)
```

Comment: I assume you are trying send message to remote machine (ssh) ?

Comment: no I am trying to have desktop notification on the current machine

Comment: Your $DISPLAY variable isn't necessarily :0 . What is the output of `echo $DISPLAY`? (or `who -u`)

Comment: The output is `$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
`
I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Ultimately it worked. I found the solution by @Vitor Abella in the following answer [The Solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/834476/how-to-use-notify-send-with-crontab?rq=1) I wish Ubuntu makes it easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Create `notify.sh` file in the home directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username=$(/usr/bin/whoami)
pid=$(pgrep -u $username nautilus)
dbus=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$dbus

/usr/bin/notify-send "How are you"
```

In the `crontab` :

```
* * * * *  DISPLAY=0:0 /bin/sh /home/YOURUSERNAME/notify.sh
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution does not works. I'm still not getting the notification

Comment: it worked like a charm. @Gardezi, create notify.sh file in your home directory with the first content supplied by @Sonu, then open crontab with `crontab -e` command in command line. than type the second content supplied by Sonu to the end of the file, use these shortcuts to save and exit: CTRL + O, ENTER, CTRL + X... That's it. but, please don't forgot to change the "netcoreps1" text in the second content supplied by @Sonu, with your current username.. for example: `* * * * *  DISPLAY=0:0 /bin/sh /home/YOURUSERNAME/notify.sh`..  it should work at start of every minute.

Comment: @Interesting Knox , Thats correct. I have improved my answer as per ur comment. Thanks. :)

Comment: finally this worked for me :)