# Cron Jobs Sporadically Running

Tags: command-line, cron

I have a computer that seems to run the cron jobs sometimes.  When I monitor the syslog, I can see the jobs mentioned, but the results of the commands are not visible.  How do I fix this?

Version of this box:

```
username:/etc$ uname -rvp
4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:25 UTC 2018 i686
```

The `/etc/crontab` file contents (complete with my notes):

```
username:/etc$ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m   = minute
# h   = hour (24-hour)
# dom = day of month
# mon = month (numeric)
# dow = day of week (sunday is 0, monday is 1, saturday is 6)
# user    = user
# command = yep
# *       = blank or null entry or wildcard

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
#25 6   * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
#47 6   * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
#52 6   1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
01 18   * * 1   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
00 20   * * 1   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
01 18   * * 2   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
00 20   * * 2   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
01 18   * * 3   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
00 20   * * 3   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
01 18   * * 4   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
00 20   * * 4   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
01 18   * * 5   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
00 20   * * 5   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
01 16   * * 6   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
00 20   * * 6   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now
## This is a test entry.
45 10   * * *   root    /usr/bin/notify-send 'Cronjob Test Message' 'This is a cronjob test message.'
46 10   * * 1   root    /usr/bin/notify-send 'Cronjob Monday Test Message' ' This is Mondays cronjob test message.'
20 11   * * *   root    /usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.'
#51 11   * * 4   root    shutdown -h now
# This line is the last line, be sure to terminated this line with a new line.
```

Please notice I have various tests going on in there.  I realize this is confusing, so I am going to simplify the `/etc/crontab` file for easier troubleshooting.  This is my new `/etc/crontab` troubleshooting file:

```
username:/etc$ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

56 11   * * *   root    /usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.'
```

Now, I watch my syslog:

```
username:/etc$ /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/tail /var/log/syslog -f
Jan 29 10:58:31 hostname dbus[730]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Jan 29 10:58:31 hostname systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Jan 29 11:10:01 hostname cron[759]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jan 29 11:10:01 hostname CRON[3240]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.')
Jan 29 11:17:01 hostname CRON[3283]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 29 11:19:01 hostname cron[759]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jan 29 11:20:01 hostname CRON[3314]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.')
Jan 29 11:34:35 hostname crontab[3386]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jan 29 11:35:46 hostname crontab[3386]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jan 29 11:55:01 hostname cron[759]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jan 29 11:56:01 hostname cron[759]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jan 29 11:56:01 hostname CRON[3537]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.')
```

The last line says at 11:56:01 it ran the command `/usr/bin/notify-send` but no pop-up message was displayed.

If I run that exact (copy & paste) command from a terminal, preceeded with `/usr/bin/sudo` the popup will appear.

```
username:/etc$ /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.'
```

If I run that exact (copy & paste) command from a terminal as the normal user logged in, the popup will appear.

```
username:/etc$ /usr/bin/notify-send 'Test' 'Message goes here.'
```

What gives?

Comment: That crontab runs for root so the notification is sent to root. To sent to a user, you would have to su to that user or put the command in that user's crontab.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/834476/how-to-use-notify-send-with-crontab

Comment: I can run the notify-send with and without sudo and it appears on a non-root display.  But, let's just assume that did not happen, and it only ran as and for root ... that still does not explain why the shutdown commands are not working.