# How to run a script in crontab?

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

I have a Script called "test.sh" in my Home Directory

I want to be able to run it in crontab.

I have added

```
* * * * * /home/tom/test.sh
```

to the crontab however it doesn't seem to be excecuting.

I can excecute ./test.sh fine normally in a Terminal Window.

**Edit:**

This is the content of my script "test.sh"

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'cd Server && ./start.sh'
```

It creates a new terminal window, changes directory to Server and runs another executable script.

I do not know if this has something to do with the script not working in Cron.

The error I get in /var/log/syslog is:

```
CRON[18694]: (tom) CMD (sh /home/tom/test.sh)
CRON[18693]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: CRON stands for **C**ommand **R**un **ON**. So when do you want it to run or how often do you want it tor run; every minute, five minutes, hour, day, week or month?

Comment: I just want to test that it works first. After I will set it to do it every midnight which I believe is 0 0 * * *

Comment: did you add it in user crontab or global crontab?

Comment: Works-in-terminal-but-doesn't-work-in-cron is one of the most common new-user questions. Try the Search bar at the top of the page to see *hundreds* of similar queries. Look up how to use [output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/how-to-log-cron-jobs) to see the error messages. Then you will *know* what is wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of `/home/tom/test.sh`. Also results from `journalctl | grep test.sh` might provide clues to you.

Comment: `cron` was never really intended for running desktop applications - if you insist on doing it, see [How to start a GUI application from cron?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514167/how-to-start-a-gui-application-from-cron)

Comment: I have tried `* * * * * su tom -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 sh /home/tom/test.sh"` however still doesn't seem to be working @steeldriver

Comment: @tdubz for *some* applications, setting `DISPLAY` is not sufficient, they need to make a connection to the desktop session's DBUS. See for example [How to use notify-send with crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/a/834495/178692). FWIW I would recommend putting the relevant `DISPLAY` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` commands inside your test.sh script.

Comment: Thank you very much @steeldriver - Cron is now executing the script after adding `eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";` to my test.sh.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, [the syntax](https://crontab.guru/) for the execution times is demonstrated here. The CronTab can be confusing, but there are [an abundance](https://linuxhandbook.com/crontab/) of guides out there to help.

Now, in your case you have:

```
* * * * * /home/tom/test.sh
```

Depending on how you edited your Crontab, this *could* be a permission issue. Using `bash`, I always did the following:

```
* * * * * sh /home/tom/test.sh
```

Which is the same as the following:

```
* * * * * /home/tom/test.sh
```

With the theory that `test.sh` has a somewhat similar structure:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in */ .*/ ; do 
    echo -n $i": " ; 
    (find "$i" -type f | wc -l) ; 
done
```

The last thing to check is that the script is executable:

```
chmod +x /home/tom/test.sh
```

For me, I performed the following on my Crontab:

```
# Example Crontab command:
# * * * * * /home/mn/Documents/Scripts/counta.sh >> /home/mn/Documents/Scripts/test
```

This was able to successfully run and output the test file as required.

Comment: @user535733 yeah, I was *wrong* so I went ahead and attempted to correct myself, but you commented too fast to see the correction ;)

Comment: should remove the dot from `./home/tom/test.sh`

Comment: steeldriver you are slow today :)=

Comment: Guys, I give up on syntax. I'm done. More damage than good!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you mean answer, right? Ehhh, if I've fumbled again on this one I'll delete it. But thanks to the other two for the pickups ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DankyNanky - It seems as though the script still does not execute properly despite using "sh" before the command. The script is definitely executable because I can run it just fine in a Terminal Window. I have edited my original question with more background information about the script I would like to run and the error I am getting. I hope that proves to be helpful.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/222512/212930