# cron unable to run .sh script - 22.04

Tags: bash, scripts, 22.04, cron, notification

I am trying to run a simple script that checks the battery percentage and shows it through a notification (`notify-send`).
The script runs correctly if ran from terminal manually: `~/path-to-script/my_script.sh` or `sh ~/path-to-script/my_script.sh` or even `bash ~/path-to-my-script/my_script.sh`.
Where correctly means that the notification is shown.

However when trying to run it through `cron` no notification appears.
This is what `crontab -e` looks like:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh ~/path-to-my-script/my_script.sh
```

I have, also, set some environment variables in `crontab` with `sudo vim /etc/crontab`:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

And this is the log from `sudo service cron status`:

```
gen 28 17:35:01 my_user CRON[7863]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user my_user(uid=1001) by (uid=0)
gen 28 17:35:01 my_user CRON[7864]: (my_user) CMD (/usr/bin/sh ~/path-to-my-script/my_script.sh)
gen 28 17:35:01 my_user CRON[7863]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
gen 28 17:35:01 my_user CRON[7863]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user my_user
```

I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 using i3 as window manager.
What could be the cause of this issue?

Please ask if more info is needed.

Comment: The log message seems to indicate that you don't have an MTA (mail transfer agent) installed.  Perhaps you can try installing that?  I'm curious why you get that message, though.  You said it runs fine on the command-line.  Why don't you create a dummy script that just does a `date >~/hello.txt` and see if the file gets updated.  If so, your problem isn't `cron`, but something it is looking for...perhaps that MTA it's complaining about.

Comment: The `No MTA installed` message is because `cron` wants to report something and can't - far simpler than installing an MTA would be to redirect the output + error streams to a log file ex. `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh ~/path-to-my-script/my_script.sh > ~/cron.log 2>&1` and examine *that*

Comment: ... in any case, the issue is likely that the process started from `cron` is not able to connect to your user's display - see for example [How to use notify-send with crontab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834476/how-to-use-notify-send-with-crontab)

Comment: @steeldriver following your suggestion I've found the message that it prints to cron.log: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`. So I've set `DISPLAY=:0` in my_script.sh according to the value returned by `echo $DISPLAY`, I've also set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to the value printed by `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. Still the issue persists.

Comment: After some research based on the `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY` I've found [this discussion](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=396123) that suggests to prepend `env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus` to the command in `crontab -e`. It works!

Answer (score 1):

The modern and clean way to do this is to use the user's [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/Timers). Missing the DBus environment variable is only [one of the many reasons why cron is obsolete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278564/524752) on modern Ubuntu Linux.

1. Paste this in `~/.config/systemd/user/battery_notification.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Sends notification about battery status

[Service]
# %h means ~
ExecStart=%h/path-to-my-script/my_script.sh
Type=oneshot
```

2. Paste this in `~/.config/systemd/user/battery_notification.timer`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Show battery notification every minute

# If you want to limit it to a specific desktop environment,
# you can change this line.
# This mostly prevents unnecessary runs in SSH or after logging out,
# and is another advantage over cron.
# EDIT: Too bad i3 has a bug that breaks this: https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/5186
#Requisite=graphical-session.target
#PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Install]
#WantedBy=graphical-session.target
WantedBy=dbus.service

[Timer]
AccuracySec=1us
# Initial delay
OnActiveSec=1s
# Period
OnUnitActiveSec=1m
```

3. Run the following:

```bash
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable battery_notification.timer
systemctl --user start battery_notification.timer # Or reboot
```

You will see that the DBus environment variable, together will *many other* missing environment variables are set properly. The program is also now a child of one of your user processes, namely `systemd --user` not cron, so it is in the proper cgroup and other namespaces.

Another advantage is that it stops after you log out or if you don't log into your specified graphical environment. Useful commands might be `systemctl --user list-timers` to check the remaining time or `systemctl --user disable battery_notification.timer && systemctl --user stop battery_notification.timer` to stop it.

Comment: Is the file in step 2 the same as the one in step 1? Namely: `~/.config/systemd/user/battery_notification.timer`

Comment: @overmach Oops, step 2 is the .timer file and step 1 was supposed to be the .service file. Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

As reported in my comment the solution turned out to be: prepending `env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus` to the command in `crontab -e` as follows:

```
*/1 * * * * env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus /usr/bin/sh ~/path-to-my-script/my_script.sh
```