# notify-send not working in dhclient dispatcher script

Tags: bash, scripts, dhcp, notify-send, dhclient

I am detecting IP assigned by dhclient and trying to show it using notify-send.
I have made a script and placed it in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d`. Content of the script is as below

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami >>/tmp/vari.txt
echo "========================>" >> /tmp/vari.txt
printenv >> /tmp/vari.txt
echo "========================>" >> /tmp/vari.txt
set >> /tmp/vari.txt
notify-send "hey"
MAINUSER=`cat /etc/passwd|grep 1000|sed "s/:.*$//g"`
su $MAINUSER -c $"notify-send \"IP assigned\""
```

I have saved it with name `test` and have given executable permission and root as owner.
All the parts of the scripts are working except for notify-send.
One thing I checked is keeping filename as `test.sh` and notify-send works from command line but dispatcher service doesn't execute it.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Try to put something like `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` before the `su` line.

Comment: thanks @FedonKadifeli but no luck. from command line notify-send runs but not via dhclient dispatch service.

Comment: Is the user with id 1000 logged in to a GUI session by the time the script runs? There was a similar (not identical to yours) discussion here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/

Comment: @Fedonkadifeli MAINUSER variable in my script fetches the user with id 1000 and showing correct user not root. Will go through the link that you have provided