# How to get gnome-screensaver-command info passed along to the script called by CRONTAB

Tags: bash, cron

There are two USERS on this computer:  jdl and experiment

CRONTAB setup (for experiment(executed every minute):

```
USER=experiment
HOME=/home/experiment
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/experiment/bin:/home/experiment/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
XAUTHORITY=/home/experiment/.Xauthority
DISPLAY=:0

*/1 * * * * /home/experiment/monitor
```

From the command prompt running a script(monitor) with: (yields Inactive)

```
if (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is inactive"); then
    # Inactive screensaver
    echo "screensaver: Inactive">>log_log.txt
elif (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"); then
    # Active screensaver
    echo "screensaver: Active">>log_log.txt
else
    # N/A active screensaver
    echo "screensaver: N/A">>log_log.txt
fi
```

But from CRONTAB(running the script: monitor)... running the same script: (yields N/A) as the scope is not a particular user

How to get the screensaver status for a particular user when the script is run from CRONTAB?

Comment: Not sure, but I have 3 things to try: ☐in your script, use `/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command` rather than `gnome-screensaver-command`; ☐begin your script with `export DISPLAY=':0.0'`; ☐set `$PATH` at the top of your script

Comment: Think a better choice would be to use a `systemd.timer` and start it as a user service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Using [Notify-send doesn't work from crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/notify-send-doesnt-work-from-crontab)

NEED TO SET DBUS:

Using the gnome-session first results pid for DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS lookup:

```
source /home/experiment/.bashrc
pid=$(pgrep -u experiment gnome-session | head -n 1)
dbus=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$dbus
export HOME=/home/experiment
export DISPLAY=:0
export USER=experiment


if (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"); then
    echo $(date) :::: $USER :::: Active>> $HOME/crondate.txt 
    uu="user: $USER   date: $(date)   screensaver: ACTIVE"
elif (gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is inactive"); then
    echo $(date) :::: $USER :::: InActive>> $HOME/crondate.txt 
    uu="user: $USER   date: $(date)   screensaver: INACTIVE"
else
    echo $(date) :::: $USER :::: N/A>> $HOME/crondate.txt 
    uu="user: $USER   date: $(date)   screensaver: N/A"
fi
```

Comment: It's great that you were able to find a working solution here. And thank you for sharing it. :-)