# Can I display lock screen when I unplug the charger?

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen

I'm running `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` and want to display the lock screen when I unplug my charger. Is there a script, plugin or program that will let me do this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. To clarify, you would like your notebook to automatically lock when it is disconnected from power? Or are you asking to have the machine wake from sleep/hibernate and show the lock screen when disconnected?

Comment: An endless script running in background can monitor battery status as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/1412872/855322 and then lock the screen as explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/493331/855322

Comment: @matigo yes i want it to automatically lock when it is disconnected from power.